# How to remove the " punctuation using .to_csv method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below:

```
#user    item   rating  time    word_count  review
3        2      4.0     131600  123         1 1 3 3 3 4 4 5 ..
......
```

The number in review denotes the word_id. When I apply the `to_csv` function:

```
df.to_csv("data.votes", sep = " ", cols = ['user','item','rating','time','word count','review'], header = False, index = False)
```

The resulting text file is like:

```
3 2 4.0 131600 123 "1 1 3 3 3 4 4 5...  101 "
```

How can I remove the annoying `"` ? It has a bad effect on running my model. Thank you in advance!

Comment: does `df['review'] = df['review'].str.replace("\"",'')` work

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for your reply. But when I call `df[review][1]`, I get `'1 1 2 2 ....'`. So I think it is added by the `to_csv` function.

Comment: Are you sure, can you try it and check the csv as this could be just the display

Comment: @EdChum I have tried, still exists. I guess it maybe caused by that file is separated by "s+" and the numbers in review text  are also separated by "s+".

Comment: Yes that would be a problem, do you have to use space as a delimiter, the default is comma

Comment: @EdChum Yes I have to. Do you have idea about reading the csvfile again and write a clean one.

Comment: Don't know, the code is probably protecting you from generating an invalid csv that can't be read back in again which is what will happen without the quotes, if you could write it out to a fixed width file then this would be fine but there is no built in method for this as you have to determine the max col widths and pad the elements